# Regeln für adjektivische Verwendung von Vornamen

Tags: adjective, person-names, inflection

Mit beispielsweise dem *viktorianischen* und dem *wilhelminischen* Zeitalter (nach Königin [Viktoria](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_(Vereinigtes_K%C3%B6nigreich)) bzw. [Wilhelm II.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_II._(Deutsches_Reich))) und dem *julianischen* und *gregorianischen* Kalender (nach [Julius Cäsar](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaius_Iulius_Caesar) bzw. [Gregor XIII.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregor_XIII.)) haben wir vier Beispiele der adjektivischen Verwendung von Vornamen (hier jener der betreffenden Herrscher bzw. eines Papstes).

Jedoch scheint es, als klängen diese Bildungen nur deshalb natürlich und vertraut, weil genannte Begriffe etabliert und folglich bekannt sind. Andere adjektivische Formen erscheinen höchst befremdlich:

- Karl/Karla → *karlianisch* … *karlanisch*?
- Friedrich/Frederike → *frederikisch*?
- August/Auguste → *augustianisch*?
- Johannes/Johanna → *johannitisch*?

Dann gibt es wiederum solche, die ein bisschen oder deutlich vertrauter klingen:

- Clemens/Clementine → *clementinisch*
- Paul/Paula/Pauline → *paulinisch*
- Felix/Felicia → *felizianisch*
- Alexander/Alexandra → *alexandrinisch*
- Martin/Martina → *martinisch*

Ich frage mich nun, ob es allgemeingültige Regeln für die Bildung von Adjektiven aus (allerlei) Vornamen gibt. Offenbar ist der Weg über die weibliche Namensform oft ausschlaggebend.

Comment: Friedrich -> *friderizianisch*, Augustus -> *augusteisch*. Generell scheint der lateinische Genitiiv maßgeblich zur Wortbildung beizutragen

Comment: Es gibt einige einfachere Formen: augustinisch, felizisch, alexandrisch. Es scheint, als wenn man an den letzten Konsonanten einfach -isch anhängen kann. Es gibt auch karlisch, zumindest als eigenen Namen, aber vielleicht möchte man zumendest zwei Silben haben.

Comment: Es gibt sehr wohl "johannitische" Vereine, etc., allen voran der Johanniter-Orden. Allerdings haben diese manchmal stattdessen "johannisch" im Namen, vielleicht trägt das ja zum Auffinden einer Antwort bei.

Answer (score 1):

Wir könnten nach der Namensherkunft unterscheiden.

Viele derer, die du genannt hast, kamen aus dem Lateinischen ins Deutsche (selbst wenn sie nicht ursprünglich im Lateinischen entstanden waren). Oft gab es dazu im (antiken oder mittelalterlichen) Latein schon Adjektive (z. B. weil eine Familie so hieß), die kann man dann eindeutschen. Die Suffixe werden seltener auch bei anderen Namen benutzt.

> konstantinisch (z. B. konstantinische Wende)
>
> [karolinisch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/karolinisch) (angeblich *carolingian* auf Englisch; [karolingisch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/karolingisch) heißt angeblich *Carolingian*)
>
> dimitrianisch (von mir erfunden zu *Dimitri*, aber folgt der Regel)

Andererseits gibt es germanische Erbworte. Da kommt -isch oder -'sch am häufigsten vor. Es kommt auch bei nichtgermanischstämmigen Namen vor.

> albertisch
>
> heinz'sch / heinzisch
>
> frank'sch (wie in [Frank'sche Formel](https://strafrecht-online.org/problemfelder/at/versuch/ruecktritt/freiwillig/) nach Reinhard Frank)
>
> jakobisch
>
> max'sch / maxisch (Konsonantencluster sind schwer auszusprechen, aber es ähnelt dem etablierten *Marx'sch*)
>
> caesarisch

Für Namen anderer Herkunft hat sich glaube ich keine Regel etabliert. Ich würde von Fall zu Fall entscheiden und sie in eine der bekannten Formen pressen.

Comment: Heißt es nicht "albertinisch"?

Comment: @äüö Das mögen wir gerne zur Debatte stellen. Eine schnelle Internetsuche deckt die [Albertiner](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albertiner) auf. Jedenfalls in denjenigen (seltenen) Kontexten, wo das Verwirrung stiften stiften kann (gehörig zu Albert oder den Albertinern) sollte man mMn _albertisch_ sagen.

Answer (score 0):

Zusätzlich zu den schon erwähnten sind auch folgende Adjektive etabliert:

Johanneisch - wird verwendet für die Schriften des Neuen Testaments, welche die Tradition einem Autor Johannes zuschreibt

Friderizianisch - bezieht sich auf Friedrich II. "*den Großen*" von Preußen und seine Zeit

Augusteisch - bezieht sich auf den römischen Kaiser Augustus und seine Zeit